# How do I create and return a Ruby class from a lambda?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a lambda that will return a stub class. This is what I've got:

```
engine_stub = lambda { |valid|
  Class.new {
    def valid?(address)
      valid
    end
  }
}
```

The lambda should return a class whose `valid?` instance method always returns the value passed to the lambda. This code fails with the error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `valid' for #<#<Class:0x007f4bf0ebd
0f0>:0x007f4bf0ebcd08>
```

So clearly the method doesn't have access to the lambda scope. I also tried this:

```
engine_stub = lambda { |valid|
  stub_class = Class.new
  def stub_class.valid?(address)
    valid
  end
  return stub_class
}
```

Which instead causes this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `valid?' for #<#<Class:0x007fecbada1138>:0x007fec
bada0df0>
```

So now I've failed to make `valid?` an instance variable.

### Summary

I'm trying to get the lambda `engine_stub` to return a class with one instance method `valid?` that returns the value passed to the lambda. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keyword `def` is a scope gate, so you should define method via `define_method{}`

```
engine_stub = -> valid do
  Class.new { define_method :valid? do valid end }
end
```

Comment: This didn't work until I removed the `class << self` block. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you need this stub for testing. In case of rspec, you probably should create stub instead of class, or if your code really needs providing class:

```
engine_stub = stub_chain(:new, :valid?, valid)
```